# Polars, sum column based on other column values in `groupby`

Tags: python-polars

I want to calculate the sum of a column in a `groupby` based on values of another column. Pretty much what `pl.Expr.value_counts` do (see example), but I want to apply a function (e.g `sum`) to a specific column, in this case the *Price* column.

I know that I could do the `groupby` on *Weather* + *Windy* and then aggregate, but, I can't do that since I have plenty of other aggregations I need to compute on only the *Weather* groupby.

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    data = {
            "Weather":["Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun","Rain","Sun"],
            "Price":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
            "Windy":["Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N"]
    }
)
```

I can get number of counts per windy day by `value_counts`

```py
df_agg = (df
        .groupby("Weather")
        .agg([
            pl.col("Windy")
                .value_counts()
                .alias("Price")
        ])
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Weather ┆ Price              │
│ ---     ┆ ---                │
│ str     ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Sun     ┆ [{"Y",2}, {"N",2}] │
│ Rain    ┆ [{"Y",2}, {"N",2}] │
└─────────┴────────────────────┘
```

I would like to do something like this:

```py
df_agg =(df
        .groupby("Weather")
        .agg([
            pl.col("Windy")
                .custom_fun_on_other_col("Price",sum)
                .alias("Price")
        ])
)
```

and, this is the result I want,

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Weather ┆ Price              │
│ ---     ┆ ---                │
│ str     ┆ list[struct[2]]    │
╞═════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Sun     ┆ [{"Y",6},{"N",14}] │
│ Rain    ┆ [{"Y",4},{"N",12}] │
└─────────┴────────────────────┘
```

(Using polars version 15.15)

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can create temporary dataframe and then join it with main dataframe.

```py
tmp = df.groupby(["Weather", "Windy"]).agg(col("Price").sum())\
        .select([pl.col("Weather"), pl.struct(["Windy", "Price"])])\
        .groupby("Weather").agg(pl.list("Windy"))
```

```py
df.groupby("Weather").agg([
    # your another aggregations ...
]).join(tmp, on="Weather")
```

```
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Weather ┆ Windy               │
│ ---     ┆ ---                 │
│ str     ┆ list[struct[2]]     │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ Rain    ┆ [{"Y",4}, {"N",12}] │
│ Sun     ┆ [{"N",14}, {"Y",6}] │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the route I'll have to go if no "direct" solution available.. Although, I would really prefer not not, for obvious reasons.